# Powershell - Loading a CSV file into a multi-dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file for help desk calls.  The same ticket might have 1,2, or even 5 records based on the number of updates it has.  (One field is different, all other fields are identical).

I want to take the mostly-duplicate records and create one record with the differences concatenated into it.  (I'm a long time programmer, this shouldn't be a problem.  But I'm brand new to PowerShell.)

I figured the best way was to load the file into a multi-dimensional array, then I can step through the records looking for duplicate ID numbers.

So, assuming that is the best way to handle this problem, how do I load the CSV file into a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Powershell has an `Import-CSV` cmdlet for importing into an array of objects. However, I don't really understand how you would import a CSV into a multi-dimensional array (unless you mean a 2-dimensional array, as opposed to a jagged array?). A CSV is inherently a 2-d structure...

Comment: I think what you would use in idiomatic powershell is pipe the results of an `Import-CSV` into a `Group-By`.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant a 2D array.

Comment: @RB. A "Group-By"?  I'm not familiar with that, and search wasn't much help.

Comment: Sorry-  I meant `Group-Object` (aka `Group`). I've posted an example of how to use both `Import-CSV` and `Group-Object`. Other useful cmdlets for record processing include `Select-Object` (for projecting out different sorts of objects - maybe you only want the first 3 fields for exampl) and `Sort-Object` (sorts the input by whatever property you specify),

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the final bit I think you'll need - flattening the distinct fields into a single value.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so without knowing your input data, here is a skeleton of how you would approach the problem in PowerShell. Remember that in PowerShell you are dealing with objects, which actually makes this a lot easier.

My input data is as shown:

```
IncidentID,Comment
IT01,"User says stuff is broken"
IT01,"All fixed"
IT02,"Printer is out of toner. Sent Moss to replace."
IT03,"Jen turned off the internet."
IT03,"Douglas is very cross - we need a fix urgently."
IT03,"Turns out Roy was playing a practical joke on Jen."
```

First, I import the CSV into an array of records - this is basically your 2d array, except that it's actually a 1-dimensional array of objects.

```
$> $records = Import-CSV myfile.csv
```

Then, we group the objects by the IncidentID

```
$> $incidents = $records | Group IncidentID
```

If we print `$incidents` now, we can see how that looks:

```
$> $incidents
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 IT01                      {@{IncidentID=IT01; Comment=User says stuff is broken}, @{IncidentID=IT01; Comment=All fixed}}
    1 IT02                      {@{IncidentID=IT02; Comment=Printer is out of toner. Sent Moss to replace.}}
    3 IT03                      {@{IncidentID=IT03; Comment=Jen turned off the internet.}, @{IncidentID=IT03; Comment=Douglas is very cros...
```

To access a single record, you can use the following syntax:

```
$> $incidents[0].Group[0]
IncidentID Comment
---------- -------
IT01       User says stuff is broken
```

Finally, to turn the array of comments into a single string, you can use the following, which will create a "Calculated Property" (in PowerShell parlance) called `Comments` which flattens the comment array into a string.

```
$> $final = $incidents | `
             Select Name, `
                    @{`
                        Name='Comments'; `
                        Expression={ $_.Group | Select -Expand Comment | Out-String }}

$> $final[0].Comments
User says stuff is broken
All fixed
```

Comment: I will try that tomorrow and let you know if I have any problems.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I think I've got that.  Now, I want to make each group a single record, in other words, concatenate all of the Comments together.  I have additional fields, so I'll add one to your database (love the examples, BTW.)

Comment: OK, I think I've got that.  Now, I want to make each group a single record, in other words, concatenate all of the Comments together.  I have more fields, so I'll add one to your database (love the examples, BTW.) All other fields in a group will be identical.

ID, Date, Comment
IT01,1/1/16, "User says stuff is broken"
IT01,1/1/16, "All fixed"
IT02,1/15/16, "Printer is out of toner. Sent Moss to replace."
IT03,2/1/16, "Jen turned off the internet."
IT03,2/1/16, "Douglas is very cross - we need a fix urgently."
IT03,2/1/16, "Turns out Roy was playing a practical joke on Jen."

Comment: $FileList = Import-Csv "U:\Call List.csv"

$incidents = $FileList | Group ID

foreach($group in $incidents)
{
   >>> What goes here?<<<
}

Comment: @Jeff - I would recommend asking a new question, describing how far you've got, what output you are currently getting, and what output you want to achieve. Ensure you include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's much easier than trying to do it through the comments on a random answer. Feel free to add a link to the new question to this answer so I'll notice it :)